What are some common ways to simulate a set of $N$ identical oblate spheroids in a laminar flow?
I was wondering if there is a software or even a general theoretical framework to implement on my own able to simulate a set of N oblate spheroids of known major and minor semi-axis in a laminar flow inside a tube of known diameter.
I am trying to derive an approximation for the deviation from the Stokes-Einstein equation for the diffusion coefficient of spheroidal Graphene Quantum Dots (GQDs) but first I wanted to simulate just the behaviour of some test particles in a laminar flow to get a grasp of the average distribution of intertia moments and principal axes with respect to the vector field generating the laminar flow.

If the particles are intended to be negligible in size, then I would think a simple scalar advection equation describing the evolution of the number density would suffice. However, I'm assuming they are of non-negligible size, then what you're looking for is usually called a multiphase flow.
While I haven't worked with such flows, I have worked on developing a 3D solver for MHD, so I can imagine that developing your own code is quite complicated and will take a long time to develop, even if you make it very bespoke to your own research (i.e., make specific assumptions that simplify functions/algorithms instead of taking a more general one).
NB: software recommendation questions are actually considered off-topic here (cf. last bullet point), so I cannot advise on existing software (I'm also not aware of any either).

Thank you so much, i should have read the off-topic list more carefully!
